# How to use regular expressions in Excel?

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have a column of values that can be numbers, letter, characters or both.
I need to sieve that column into a new column with the following rules:

1) if a cell contains numbers then concatenate "89"

2) if a cell contains numbers and hyphens, trim the hyphens and concatenate 89

3) if a cell contains letters or other spec characters, say string

```
column    resultingColumn
1234      123489
12-34hk   string
&23412    string
99-9      99989
34-4      34489
```

I tried but its not as easy as it seemed

```
Function SC(strIn As String) As String
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
     With objRegex
     //i am not sure how to list the rules here
    .ignorecase = True
    SC = .Replace(strIn, vbNullString)
    End With
    End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not require Regular Expressions.  Consider:

```
Function aleksei(vIn As Variant) As Variant
    Dim z As Variant
    z = Replace(vIn, "-", "")
    If IsNumeric(z) Then
        aleksei = z & "89"
    Else
        aleksei = "string"
    End If
End Function
```

Edit#1:

Based on Nirk's comment, if the decimal point is to be excluded as part of a "number, then use instead:

```
Function aleksei(vIn As Variant) As Variant
    Dim z As Variant, zz As Variant
    z = Replace(vIn, "-", "")
    zz = Replace(z, ".", "A")
    If IsNumeric(zz) Then
        aleksei = z & "89"
    Else
        aleksei = "string"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: -1: "123.45" contains the special character '.' but is numeric

Comment: Hi Nirk:  Why do you think 123.45 is not numeric?  ....it looks numeric to me (and VBA)

Comment: `IsNumeric("123.45")` is True, BUT as the question is stated you should be saying "string"

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regular expression or even VBA for this: set B2 to the following formula and fill down:

```
 =IF(SUM(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,"-"},"")))-10*LEN(A2)=0,SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","")&"89","string")
```

What this does is calculate the lengths if we remove each of the characters in the class `[0-9\-]` from the text.  If there are no other characters, then we will have removed each of the characters once, so the total sum of lengths of the strings is 10 times the original string.  If there are extraneous characters, they won't be deleted and so the sum will exceed the threshold.